# The method build() is undefined for the type OpenCameraManager

Tags: android, zxing

I have encountered a problem in my application.  I have Zxing and in the CameraManager class, I have an error.  The error I get `The method build() is undefined for the type OpenCameraManager`.  Here is the code.

```
public synchronized void openDriver(SurfaceHolder holder) throws IOException {
Camera theCamera = camera;
if (theCamera == null) {
  theCamera = new OpenCameraManager().build().open();
  if (theCamera == null) {
    throw new IOException();
  }
  camera = theCamera;
}
```

I get the error on this line:
     theCamera = new OpenCameraManager().build().open();
What's wrong here?  I also get the same error in other classes, where `build()` is.  I've been banging my head for quite some time.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This method doesnt exist in the code you are calling. That's what the error says. Is there something more here? Just look at OpenCameraManager to see what methods it actually has.